# Non-Breaking Hyphen Sequence Interpreted as Cmd-hyphen (Zoom out)

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome

I'm trying to insert a non-breaking hyphen into a web app in Google Chrome. The key sequence is ⌘⇧-. Whenever I type this key sequence into a program (tested Notes, Textedit, and Chrome itself), it is interpreted as ⌘-, which is mapped to either reduce text size or zoom out. How can I enter non-breaking hyphens without using the character viewer and why does this peculiar behaviour occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enter a non-breaking hyphen in Google Chrome just enter `&#8209;`: ‑ *(<- check the source by opening my answer in the edit mode)*.
The underlaying web app has to support this though.

A universal method to enter a non-breaking hyphen for all apps is to enable "Unicode Hex Input" from System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Input Source, choose it in the menubar and enter <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>.

For Apple and probably some other apps you may set up an auto correct entry like nbhy -> ‑. You have to type <kbd>n</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>space</kbd><kbd>delete</kbd> to add a non-breaking hyphen then.

With apps like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/faq.html.en#unicode-hex-input) or Ukelele you may reduce the effort by remapping key strokes.

---

I still have to investigate the behavior to add an explanation why this happens.

Comment: Good ideas! Also, I could use the source editor/inspect element an insert said code if the app doesn't support it being directly inserted.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the excellent answer by klanomath, another method would be to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> simultaneously to get the Character Viewer (alternatively select in the menubar `Edit` > `Emoji & Symbols`). In the Character Viewer, use the search function to find the "non-breaking hyphen". By double-clicking it will be inserted.